# Bitrix — почему не выгружаются дополнительные свойства?

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с

В программе 1с, создал дополнительные свойства, в которых указываю старую цену и скидку. В bitrix в админке создал данные дополнительные свойства (прикрепил скрин), но после выгрузки данные свойства пустые, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка или как правильно добавлять свойства? Прикрепил скрин файла import.xml где указаны эти свойства.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не буду напоминать, что механика скидок в Битрикс изменилась и поэтому "старые" статьи в инете вряд ли помогу. Вы, похоже нашли решение своего вопроса по скидкам.

Знаете, так поверхностно, мне показалось, что все-таки, надо писать файлы XML в части свойств немного по другому. Могу дать ссылку на документацию Битрикс, где описано. А пока напомню, как должен выглядеть файл обмена для свойств

```
<ЗначенияСвойства>
    <Ид>DIAM2</Ид>
    <Значение>0</Значение>
    <ЗначенияСвойства>
        <Значение>0</Значение>
    </ЗначенияСвойства>
</ЗначенияСвойства>

<ЗначенияСвойства>
    <Ид>CML2_ACTIVE</Ид>
    <Значение>true</Значение>
</ЗначенияСвойства>
```

Нужен будет скриншот из "свойств инфоблока" дополнительно? Могу приложить пример.

В 1С это выглядит как-то так

```
СписокЗначенийCML.ЗаписатьНачалоЭлемента("ЗначенияСвойства");       
    ЗаписатьТекстовойУзел(СписокЗначенийCML, "Ид", "DIAM3");
    ЗаписатьТекстовойУзел(СписокЗначенийCML, "Значение",СтрЗаменить(СокрЛП(НоменклатураСсылкаА.Диаметр),",",".") );
    СписокЗначенийCML.ЗаписатьНачалоЭлемента("ЗначенияСвойства");
        ЗаписатьТекстовойУзел(СписокЗначенийCML, "Значение", СтрЗаменить(СокрЛП(НоменклатураСсылкаА.Диаметр),",",".") );
    СписокЗначенийCML.ЗаписатьКонецЭлемента();
СписокЗначенийCML.ЗаписатьКонецЭлемента();
```

Если затруднительно писать в 1С, **еще можете в обработчике init.php**  написать изменение свойств у загруэаемого элемента при загрузке данных из 1С